# Pull to refresh for UICollectionView in ViewController jumps when applying NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've added a UICollectionView as a subview to my ViewController.  I've also set a UIRefreshControl for the UICollectionView which applies a NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot when I pull down to refresh.  The animation jumps when applying the snapshot (note this happens even when the navigator bar title isn't large.)

[image]

Here are the relevant snippets of code

```
var collectionView: UICollectionView! = nil
var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Item>! = nil

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: 
    generateLayout())
    view.addSubview(collectionView)
    collectionView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .systemGroupedBackground
    self.collectionView = collectionView
    collectionView.delegate = self

    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doSomething), for: .valueChanged)
    collectionView.refreshControl = refreshControl
}
    
@objc func doSomething(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        var dataSourceSnapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Item>()
        // add data
        dataSource.apply(dataSourceSnapshot)
    }
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

Are there any changes I can make to apply the snapshot without the sudden jump?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Apple Engineers can not properly solve that issue since iOS 6.

Long story short: you don't want to `endRefreshing` while your scroll view `isTracking`. `UIRefreshControl` modifies `contentInset` and `contentOffset` of the scrollView, and it always caused jumps like that.

If you have a network request state anywhere, or any other flag indicating that the loading is in progress you could simply do:

```
@objc func doSomething(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
    loading = true
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        var dataSourceSnapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Item>()
        // add data
        dataSourceSnapshot.appendSections([.test])
        dataSourceSnapshot.appendItems([.test])
        self.dataSource.apply(dataSourceSnapshot)
        self.loading = false
        
    }
}

override func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    if !loading && collectionView.refreshControl!.isRefreshing {
        collectionView.refreshControl!.endRefreshing()
    }
}
```

I don't quite like `loading` flags like that, but that's just an example. Hopefully you have better source of truth indicating if some "work" is still in progress.

I guess there might be a nicer way of solving it (by patching classes in runtime), but it usually takes time to investigate. I wonder if that solution satisfies your needs.